# Azure keyvault china limitations

Tags: azure-keyvault

Do we have any limitations for Azure KeyVault in China? Earlier I have been informed that HSM is not supported in China Region. Is this still true? Any link/documentation?

Comment: I found one thread on same.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HSM support is not available in China.

github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2009